# Separating "client.load_extension('name here')" from one another in discord.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

A quick and simple question regarding in separating `client.load_extension`. So I have 2 *(possibly more later on)* cogs that I want to use, but when I try to load both of them through a comma `client.load_extension('commands.dev-only.purge', 'commands.dev-only.echo')`. When I run it,  it just says

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Admin/Desktop/bot/main.py", line 27, in <module>
    client.load_extension('commands.dev-only.purge', 'commands.dev-only.echo')
TypeError: load_extension() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

The only other way I know so far, is duplicating the code..

```
client.load_extension('commands.dev-only.purge')
client.load_extension('commands.dev-only.echo')
```

Any help would be appreciated! Just started a couple weeks ago, my bad if this question might've sounded dumb to you

Comment: What exactly is your question? You have a method of separating the cog loads. Do you specifically want to use something like `client.load_extension('commands.dev-only.purge', 'commands.dev-only.echo')`?

Comment: Yeah, Im basically trying to find a better and shorter way of doing that rather than duplicating it, my bad for the confusion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would have to set up your own function to handle this.

```py
from discord.ext import commands

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')

def load_extensions(*args):
    for extension in args:
        client.load_extension(extension)

load_extensions('commands.dev-only.purge', 'commands.dev-only.echo')

client.run('token')
```